# How to calculate my encoding sha256 maximum int lenght?

Tags: python, calculation

I use this little code in a function to generate immutable hash of strings and store it.
My problem is i don't know how to find the max possible value with sha256 :7 'little' ???

```
int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(value.encode('utf-8')).digest()[:7], 'little')
```

Comment: Max possible value... of what? You're creating a single hash, a single bytestring, and single int here. What group of values are you trying to find the max of? Multiple strings?

Comment: Hi @MattDMo, i would like to know the maximum possible hash value converted into INT from my code. the maximum sha256 is 2^64-1 but i trunc it.

Comment: @Jonito Technically, the maximum possible sha256, when interpreted as an unsigned integer, is 2^256-1. Hence the name sha256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have seven bytes, and you turn that into an integer, the maximum value is the same as the maximum value of a (7*8) bit integer, because there are 8 bits in a byte. The largest value of a 56-bit unsigned integer is 2**56 - 1, and the smallest value is 0.

```
>>> 2**56 - 1
72057594037927935
```

What about negative values? int.from_bytes() interprets its value as unsigned by default, so you won't have negative values.

Comment: Awesome, you fixed my issue and now i catch the whole picture !
Thanks you very much @Nick !